# Why Redux doesn't re-render component if states are different?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component which gets data in `componentDidMount()` method:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    try {
        this.res = await API.post(`clicks`, {data});
        this.props.setClicksData(this.res.data);
    } catch (err) {
        this.props.setClicksData(1);
    }
}
```

When the server thrown an error I set clicks data to anything different from previous state. This is my `reducer`:

```
const initialState = {}

const tableReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    let newState;
    switch (action.type) {
        case `SET_CLICKS`:
            newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
            newState = action.data;

            console.log(state);
            console.log(newState);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(state) === JSON.stringify(newState))

            return newState;

        default: return state;
    }
}

export default ipReducer;
```

From `console.log` I see that the data objects are different and stringify proved it. My log is:

```
{} 
1 
false
```

My Redux connection in component is regular:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    tableData: state.table.clicks,
})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        setClicksData: (data) => {
            return dispatch(setClicksData(data));
        },
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ClicksTable)
```

I checked the imports. It's fine. So why Redux doesn't re-render the component if the states are different? Please help!

**UPDATE:**
After action `state.table` should be:

```
{
    totalGood: int,
    totalBad: int,
    clicks: [{}, {}, {}...]
}
```

My Action is:

```
export const setClicksData = (data) => {
    return {
        type: 'SET_CLICKS',
        data,
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify why you are doing `newState = action.data;` right after doing `newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));`? Are you wanting to use `state` or `action.data`? Also what do you intend the structure of state to be? You are going from an object `{}` to a number `1`. Did you intend to instead initialize as a number such as `0`?

Comment: Does your reducer receive `state.table`? You don't need to copy the entire object, that is very inefficient. Can you show us what state.table should be, what the action is and what the state should be after the action?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky It would be better to rename state to previousState. Initial state are always {} on start but when app is running it may change and I have to use previousSate. In this case want use action.data.

Comment: One point I'd like to make - *don't make your lifecycle functions asynchronous*. That completely goes against the notion of a function that executes at a particular point in the rendering lifecycle. If you need to handle async behaviour, use something like sagas or thunks.

Comment: @HMR I updated my question with aditioanl code.See Updates. How to check if my reducer receive `state.table`?